# Is there a special blessing for wearing the Bigdei Kehuna?

Tags: blessing, kohen-priest, bigdei-kehunah

Would the Kohanim recite a blessing upon wearing the Bigdei Kehunah, and if yes, what was it, and would they recite a blessing for each garment individually, or one for all of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q1:

> Would the Kohanim recite a blessing upon wearing the Bigdei Kehunah

R. Yaaqobh Greenwald's Beer Yaaqobh (p. 192):

> ומצינו בארצות החיים סי' יט שכתב בפשיטות שמברכים על לבישת בגדי כהונה
> אמנם בנחל איתן סוף הספר כשמונה את כל הברכות אינו מונה ברכה זו ברשימת
> הברכות ובפשטות הטעם משום שאין זו מצוה בפני עצמה אלא הכשר לעבודה ועל
> הצד שמברכים לכאורה יכול לברך אף אחר שלבש את הבגדים ונחשב זה עובר
> לעשייתן מאחר שעיקר המצוה היא שיהא לבוש בהם בשעת העבודה
>
> We've found that the Arsoth ha-Haim (siman 19) writes plainly that
> indeed they did bless on donning the priestly garments, however the
> Nahal Ethan, where it catalogues all of the berakhoth does not
> include any blessing for the donning of the priestly garments.
> Presumably this is because he holds that it is not an independent
> miswah (commandment) unto itself but is rather a preperatory function
> of the 'abhodah (Temple service)... and in the view that one does
> bless, one could still bless after donning the garments and it would
> still be considered to have been recited 'obher le'asiyathan (prior to
> its performance) since the essence of the miswah is that the priest be
> so enclothed at the time of the 'abhodah (Temple service).

Q2:

> if yes, what was it

R. Menahem Pinhas Shtibel wrote (Ohel ha-'Eduth, p. 233):

> נחלקו הראשונים אם לבישת בגדי כהונה היא מצוה והרמב"ם בספר המצוות מנה
> אותה למ"ע והנה באילת השחר בזבחים דף פח מסתפק אם לפי הרמב"ם היה ברכה על
> לבישת בגדי כהונה ומרן הגרח"ק שליט"א כתב לי נדפס בתורה יבקשו מפיהו עפ"י
> הגמ' במנחות דף מב דכל מצוה שאין עשייתה גמר המצוה אין צריך לברך וה"נ
> אין עשייתה גמר המצוה כי צריך את העבודה אמנם לכאורה נחלקו בזה אחרונים
> גבי מה שמותר ללבוש הבגדים בשעת עבודה במקדש אם הוי עשה דעבודה או עשה
> דלבישת בגדים ולכאורה אם הוי כוח דחיה בעצם הלבישה חשיב עשה גמורה ושמא
> יש לחלק בין בגדי כה"ג לכה"ד וכששאלתי את מרן הגר"ד לנדו שליט"א אמר
> דכיון שלא מצינו אפשר שלא היה ברכה ואף אם יש בה את כללי הראשונים בברכות
> דיש תשובה שהרשב"א כתב לבנו דכל הטעמים שכתב בתשובה יח הם לא עיקר הטעם
> אלא מה שרצו חז"ל לתקן תיקנו ומה שלא תיקנו לא תיקנו אמנם באמת מצינו
> בראשונים ברכות שלא מוזכרות בגמ' עי' רש"י עירובין נ' על סמיכה ועוד ומרן
> הגראי"ל זצ"ל דן שאם הכהנים בירכו היו צריכים לברך אשר קדשנו בקדשתו של
> אהרן כמו שמברכים על ברכת כהנים ועל אכילת תרומה כיון שכל המצוה הזו באה
> ע"י הקדושה מאהרן והגרמ"מ שולזינגר זצ"ל ציין לדברי הארצות החיים שבתוך
> דבריו כתב שבירכו על לבישת בגדי כהונה אשר קידשנו במצוותיו וציונו
>
> The Rishonim are divided on whether donning the priestly vestments are
> a miswah unto itself, the Rambam in the Sefer ha-Miswoth counts it as
> a positive commandment and the Ayeleth ha-Shahar (Zebhahim 88)
> equivocates over whether the Rambam held that there is a blessing on
> donning the priestly vestments. R. Haim Kanievsky wrote to me (printed
> in BaTorah Yebhakshu Mipihu) that according to the Gemara in Menahoth
> (42) every miswah in which its performance does not complete a miswah
> there is no need to bless upon it, and so to here its performance does
> not complete the miswah for the ‘abhodah is still required to be
> performed. However it would appear that the Aharonim are divided on
> what clothing it is is permitted to wear during the ‘abhodah in the
> Miqdash (Temple), if it is a positive command as an aspect of the
> ‘abhodah or is it a positive command of wearing the vestments and it
> would appear that if it has a power of deferral in the essence of the
> donning of the vestments then it would absolutely be considered a
> complete positive commandment [unto itself]. Perhaps one can
> differentiate between the clothes of the Kohen Gadol (High Priest) and
> the Kohen Hedyot (common Priest) and when I asked R. Dobh Landau he
> said that since we haven’t found [any blessing explicitly mentioned by
> Hazal] it’s possible that there was no blessing even if it otherwise
> conforms to the principles transmitted by the Rishonim about
> blessings, for there is a responsum by the Rashba in which he writes
> to his son that all of the rationales the he writes about in responsum
> 18 they are not the fundamental rationales rather whatever Hazal
> wanted to enact, they enacted and whatever they didn’t want to enact
> they didn’t enact. However in truth we find among the Rishonim
> blessings that aren’t mentioned in the Talmud (see Rashi ‘Erubhin 50
> on semikhah and more) and R. Aharon Yehuda Leib Shteinman adjudged
> that if the Kohanim blessed, they would have been required in a manner
> in which the blessing is commenced with “that has sanctified us with
> the sanctity of Aharon” such as when they bless in Birkhath Kohanim
> and upon the consumption of Terumah, since all of these miswoth are
> dependent upon the sanctity from Aharon. R. Moshe Mordekhai Shulsinger
> notes that based on the words of the Arsoth ha-Haim it would seem that
> the blessing ought commence with “that has sanctified us with His
> commandments and commanded…”

Q3:

> would they recite a blessing for each garment individually, or one for all of them?

[Mekhon Torath ha-Qorbanoth](https://www.hakorbanot.com/), an organization dedicated to promoting the study of laws appertaining to the Miqdash (Temple), so that they may be readily implemented when it is rebuilt puts out a periodical. In Gilyon Torath ha-Qorbanoth, vol. 42, p. 3:

> הנה המנחת חינוך מצוה צט יג הביא מהגמ' ביומא דאסור
> שתיקדם לבישת שום בגד ללבישת המכנסיים וחוקר מה הדין אם הקדים את לבישת
> הכתונת למכנסיים האם צריך להסירה וללבוש כסדרן או שמא הרי זה דומה לדברי
> הט"ז שאע"פ שצריך להקדים תפילין של יד לתפילין של ראש אם עבר והניח של
> ראש קודם אין צריך להסירן וכתב הגאון רבי אברהם יעקב זילברשטיין שליט"א
> בספרו אבני חן דנראה דשאני תפילין ששתי מצוות הן של יד ושל ראש ואין
> מעכבות זו את זו וכשהניח של ראש קודם כבר נגמרה מצותה ולכן אין צריך
> להסירה מה שאין כן בבגדי כהונה כל הבגדים הוי מצוה אחת של לבישה ולכן אם
> הקדים הכתונת יצטרך להסירה שהרי עדיין יכול לתקן זאת שעוד לא נגמרה מצות
> הלבישה עכת"ד ולפי זה נראה דודאי שהברכה תהיה כללית ולא פרטית על כל בגד
>
> The Minhath Hinukh (Miswah 99, 13) cites the Gemara in Yoma that it is
> forbidden to clothe one’s self into any garment prior to clothing
> one’s self in pants, and so we investigate what is the law if one
> dresses in the ketoneth before putting on pants, does he need to
> remove it in order to get dressed according to the proper order, or
> perhaps it is similar to the Ture Zahabh who holds that even though
> one ought wrap the tefillin of the arm prior to the tefillin of the
> head, if he has transgressed and already placed the head tefillin on
> he does not need to remove it. R. Abraham Yaaqobh Zilberstein in his
> book Abhnei Hen explains that it appears that this due to the fact
> that tefillin is comprised of two miswoth, that of the arm tefillin
> and that of the head tefillin, and one is not me’aqebh (preventative)
> of the other, accordingly when one places the tefillin of the head on
> first he has already fully completed the performance of that miswah
> and accordingly he does not need to remove it [so that he can put on
> the tefillin of the arm and then return the tefillin of the head].
> However, the same is not the case with the priestly vestments, donning
> all of the garments is collectively one miswah of wearing them, and so
> if one has first put on the ketoneth, he would need to remove it as he
> can still rectify it as the miswah of donning the priestly vestments
> has not yet been completed in its entirety (until here is the
> substance of his words). And according to this, it would appear that
> certainly a blessing over the donning of the priestly vestments would
> be over them collectively and not individually on each garment.